# JPA Embeddable can have ElementCollection<Embeddable> property

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

can JPA ElementCollection Embeddable have ElementCollection List Embeddable property?

```
  @Entity
  class Person {
  @ElementCollection
    private List<Address> addressList;
  }


 @Embeddable
    public class Address {
      private String city;
      private String state;
      private String countary;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Phone> phones;

      ...
    }
    @Embeddable
    public class Phone {
      private String type;
      private String areaCode;
      private String number;
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have that, if you try your configuration you will have something like this.

http://postimg.org/image/pc0f3cxbp/

Also Embeddable types can have Collection Relationship to another entities this allowed by JPA.

Taking from specs JSR317

> An embeddable class may be used to represent the state of another
>   embeddable class.
>
> An embeddable class (including an embeddable class within another
>   embeddable class) may contain a collection of a basic type or other
>   embeddable class.
>
> An embeddable class may contain a relationship to an entity or
>   collection of entities. Since instances of embeddable classes
>   themselves have no persistent identity, the relationship from the
>   referenced entity is to the entity that contains the embeddable
>   instance(s) and not to the embeddable itself.
>
> An embeddable class that is used as an embedded id or as a map key
>   must not contain such a relationship

**UPDATE**

According to your question if embeddables can contain a list of embeddables this is possible and can be done as picture in this answer suggest, **BUT** regarding if and ElementCollection can contain an embeddables with another element collection the answer is **NO**

Trying to do that will cause.

> Mapping contains an embeddable "examples.model.Address" with a
>   prohibited mapping "phones", element collections may not contain
>   embeddables with element collection mappings

Comment: Is this case scenario possible : Entity has Collection of Embeddedable of Class1 and  Embeddedable Class1 has collection of Embeddedable Class2 ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, as you can see in my attached images Address is embeddable and it contains a list of embeddable class phones, don't forget to accept my answer if was helpful

Comment: Thanks for your response , I get your point that Embeddable can have ElementCollection Embeddable but did not understand how it can be possible that ElementCollection List<AddressEmbeddable> have ElementCollection List<PhoneEmbeddable> property because AddressEmbeddable have no primary so how can AddressEmbeddable will get its connected phone ? Please explain  ....

Comment: Based in your new example of list inside a list of embeddables, the answer is not as you imagine this can not be done as you dont have a way to link each other, see the update in my answer